# Adding transition to d3.drag() behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm close to finish my first project with d3.js. It calculates the potential energy available to a skier and I want to calculate the expected speed of the skier if all this energy is converted to kinetic energy. The final thing I want is to add a transition to the skier when he is dropped. I want the skier to always transit to the black circle on the right (p2). The duration of the transition doesn't matter right now. Is there an easy way to accomplish this task?

[image: example]

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 800;
const skierIconSvg = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg';
const gate =
  'https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1k-mtzjW05U6KZKNt0kAI2pWqKsXFobptsa9kz6grYzA/edit?usp=sharing';

const [p1, p2, p3] = [
  [80, 130],
  [600, 170],
  [750, 190],
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

// Store a reference to the span we're going to update
const skierHeight = d3.select('#skier-height');

const vek = document.querySelector('#vekt');
console.log(vek.value);

const line = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'black');

const connection = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'green');

const projection = svg
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('cursor', 'move')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
  .attr('stroke-width', 30);

const point = g
  .selectAll('image')
  .data([p1, p2])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .subject(([x, y]) => ({
      x,
      y,
    }))
    .on('drag', dragged)
  );

const skier = g
  .append('image')
  .attr('id', 'skier')
  .datum(p3)
  .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-50, -40)')
  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .subject(([x, y]) => ({
      x,
      y,
    }))
    .on('drag', dragged)
  );

update();

function dragged(d) {
  d[0] = d3.event.x;
  d[1] = d3.event.y;
  update();
  potensiellEnergi();
}

function update() {
  const t = (width + height) / distance(p1, p2);

  const l1 = interpolate(p1, p2, t);

  const l2 = interpolate(p2, p1, t);
  const p = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));

  connection.attr('x1', p3[0]).attr('y1', p3[1]);
  connection.attr('x2', p[0]).attr('y2', p[1]);
  projection.attr('cx', p[0]).attr('cy', p[1]);
  line.attr('x1', l1[0]).attr('y1', l1[1]);
  line.attr('x2', l2[0]).attr('y2', l2[1]);
  point.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);
  skier.attr('x', (d) => d[0]).attr('y', (d) => d[1]);

  skierHeight.text(`${getHeight(p, p1, p2).toFixed(2)} meter`);
}

function distance([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
  return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
}

function interpolate([x1, y1], [x2, y2], t) {
  return [x1 + (x2 - x1) * t, y1 + (y2 - y1) * t];
}

function project([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]) {
  const x21 = x2 - x1,
    y21 = y2 - y1;
  const x31 = x3 - x1,
    y31 = y3 - y1;
  return (x31 * x21 + y31 * y21) / (x21 * x21 + y21 * y21);
}

function getHeight([xp, yp], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
  // Note that y is counted from top to bottom, so higher y means
  // a point is actually lower.

  // First, the total height is 100 metres.
  const pxPerMeter = (y2 - y1) / 100;

  // Calculate the height diff in pixels
  const heightDiffPx = y2 - yp;

  // Now transform it to meters
  return heightDiffPx / pxPerMeter;
}

function vektVelger() {
  const vektVerdi = document.querySelector('#vekt');
  const vektDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-vekt');

  vektDisplay.innerHTML = vektVerdi.value;
}

function potensiellEnergi() {
  const vektVerdi = parseInt(document.querySelector('#skier-vekt').textContent);
  const skierHeight = parseInt(
    document.querySelector('#skier-height').textContent
  );
  const potEDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-potentialenergi');
  const potEnergi = `${vektVerdi * skierHeight * 9.8}`;
  return (potEDisplay.innerHTML = `${potEnergi}`);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-axis.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Forsøk på å lage en tutorial i JavaScript og D3.js</h1>
  <h2>Høydeforskjell: <span id="skier-height"></span></h2>
  <h2>Vekt: <span id="skier-vekt">70</span> kg</h2>
  <h2>
    Gravitasjonskraft (fg): <span id="skier-gravitasjon">9.8</span> m/sek/sek
  </h2>
  <h2>Potential Energy: <span id="skier-potentialenergi">0</span> KJOULE</h2>

  <svg width="800" height="300"></svg>
  <form>
    Velg utøverens vekt:
    <input type="number" id="vekt" placeholder="Velg utøverens vekt" />
  </form>
  <input type="button" value="velg" onclick="vektVelger()" />

  <script src="skier.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the transition below. The skier first drops to the ground, and when that transition is done, they slide to the end. You could even use [one of these](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/1ea51d03775b9650e8dfd03474e202fe) transition easing methods to make them gain speed along the way!

I ran into some problems with your packages. I don't see why you had all these lines in your HTML, but they broke d3.transition:

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-axis.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Removing all of them and leaving only `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>` was completely fine.

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 800;
const skierIconSvg = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg';
const gate =
    'https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1k-mtzjW05U6KZKNt0kAI2pWqKsXFobptsa9kz6grYzA/edit?usp=sharing';

const [p1, p2, p3] = [
    [80, 130],
    [600, 170],
    [750, 190],
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

// Store a reference to the span we're going to update
const skierHeight = d3.select('#skier-height');

const vek = document.querySelector('#vekt');
console.log(vek.value);

const line = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'black');

const connection = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'green');

const projection = svg
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none');

const g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
    .attr('stroke-width', 30);

const point = g
    .selectAll('image')
    .data([p1, p2])
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .call(
        d3
            .drag()
            .subject(([x, y]) => ({
                x,
                y,
            }))
            .on('start', () => {
              // Interrupt all transitions
              skier.interrupt();
              connection.interrupt();

              // Update the value of p3 to wherever the skier happened to be
              // This will stop him dead in his tracks instead of snapping him back to the old position
              p3[0] = Number(skier.attr('x'));
              p3[1] = Number(skier.attr('y'));
            })
            .on('drag', dragged)
    );

const skier = g
    .append('image')
    .attr('id', 'skier')
    .datum(p3)
    .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-50, -40)')
    .call(
        d3
            .drag()
            .subject(() => ({
                // Use where the skier is, not where he's supposed to be
                x: Number(skier.attr('x')),
                y: Number(skier.attr('y')),
            }))
            .on('start', () => {
              // Interrupt all transitions
              skier.interrupt();
              connection.interrupt();
            })
            .on('drag', dragged)
            .on('end', dropSkier)
    );

update();

function dragged(d) {
    d[0] = d3.event.x;
    d[1] = d3.event.y;
    update();
    potensiellEnergi();
}

function update() {
    const t = (width + height) / distance(p1, p2);

    const l1 = interpolate(p1, p2, t);

    const l2 = interpolate(p2, p1, t);
    const p = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));

    connection.attr('x1', p3[0]).attr('y1', p3[1]);
    connection.attr('x2', p[0]).attr('y2', p[1]);
    projection.attr('cx', p[0]).attr('cy', p[1]);
    line.attr('x1', l1[0]).attr('y1', l1[1]);
    line.attr('x2', l2[0]).attr('y2', l2[1]);
    point.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);
    skier.attr('x', (d) => d[0]).attr('y', (d) => d[1]);

    skierHeight.text(`${getHeight(p, p1, p2).toFixed(2)} meter`);
}
function distance([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
}

function interpolate([x1, y1], [x2, y2], t) {
    return [x1 + (x2 - x1) * t, y1 + (y2 - y1) * t];
}

function project([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]) {
    const x21 = x2 - x1,
        y21 = y2 - y1;
    const x31 = x3 - x1,
        y31 = y3 - y1;
    return (x31 * x21 + y31 * y21) / (x21 * x21 + y21 * y21);
}

function getHeight([xp, yp], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
    // Note that y is counted from top to bottom, so higher y means
    // a point is actually lower.

    // First, the total height is 100 metres.
    const pxPerMeter = (y2 - y1) / 100;

    // Calculate the height diff in pixels
    const heightDiffPx = y2 - yp;

    // Now transform it to meters
    return heightDiffPx / pxPerMeter;
}

function vektVelger() {
    const vektVerdi = document.querySelector('#vekt');
    const vektDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-vekt');

    vektDisplay.innerHTML = vektVerdi.value;
}

function potensiellEnergi() {
    const vektVerdi = parseInt(document.querySelector('#skier-vekt').textContent);
    const skierHeight = parseInt(
        document.querySelector('#skier-height').textContent
    );
    const potEDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-potentialenergi');
    const potEnergi = `${vektVerdi * skierHeight * 9.8}`;
    return (potEDisplay.innerHTML = `${potEnergi}`);
}

function dropSkier(d) {
  const projection = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));
  skier
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    // First down to the ground
    .attr('x', projection[0])
    .attr('y', projection[1])
    .on("end", () => {
      skier
        .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        // First down to the ground
        .attr('x', p2[0])
        .attr('y', p2[1]);
    });
    
    // Remove the line together with the skier
    connection
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      // First down to the ground
      .attr('x1', projection[0])
      .attr('y1', projection[1]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Forsøk på å lage en tutorial i JavaScript og D3.js</h1>
        <h2>Høydeforskjell: <span id="skier-height"></span></h2>
        <h2>Vekt: <span id="skier-vekt">70</span> kg</h2>
        <h2>
            Gravitasjonskraft (fg): <span id="skier-gravitasjon">9.8</span> m/sek/sek
        </h2>
        <h2>Potential Energy: <span id="skier-potentialenergi">0</span> KJOULE</h2>

        <svg width="800" height="300"></svg>
        <form>
            Velg utøverens vekt:
            <input type="number" id="vekt" placeholder="Velg utøverens vekt" />
        </form>
        <input type="button" value="velg" onclick="vektVelger()" />

        <script src="skier.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing. I think I have added on these packages from reading the documentation that says they should be included. Your solution is almost perfect but what is the weird mouse event when you try to drag skier several times? I have had similar effects on my previous drag behaviour but don't know why they occur. Do you?

Comment: Ah, when you drag it several times, it registers drag-"end"s inbetween and starts the animation. You can [cancel any pending transitions](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/tree/v1.3.2#selection_interrupt) using `skier.interrupt()` and `connection.interrupt()` inside `on("drag")`

Comment: I appreciate all your help and input to my project. To understand d3.js on the level you do, is it really just to fork examples on observable and read the documentation. I feel the documentation sometimes is a bit overwhelming and d3.js specific courses focus almost entirely on visualizing data.

Comment: I agree, both that the docs can be overwhelming and the courses too narrow. d3 can be very complex, so I like to stick with code examples from mbostock (the creator) or d3noob (an expert) if possible. They are often the easiest to understand

Comment: http://cmagelssen.no/skier.html - Final version :) I wasn't able to understand where I should put the interrupt. Shall I put it in the drag function?

Comment: Looks good! I've updated the answer to fix it. Just put the interrupt inside `drag().on('start')`. I also noticed that after the animation, as soon as you dragged the skier, it would snap back to the old location (before the descent). I fixed that by using `skier.attr('x')` instead of `d.x` inside `drag.subject()`. You can see that in the example as well.